# Salesforce Jira integration {Button Need to Disable}

Tags: apex, community

I had integrated SF to JIRA

Added "CREATE JIRA" button into my SF CASE.

Once a case is saved and user click on the CREATE JIRA button, the JIRA ISSUE will create for that case.

Now I want to set some condition, once the JIRA Issue will create for the particular case, the button will de-activate or the person is unable to create the new JIRA Issue from the salesforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. Have a field on the case that indicates a JIRA case has been created. 
   Then on the button check that field and present an alert indicating that a new case cannot be created
2. Use record types and page layouts to remove the button from the page. Use the button or workflows to set the record type to one that does not have the button

Comment: Oh yeah! 10k get!!=) You are welcome!